# Igualar el ancho de un elemento a otro existente

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `span` con clase '.uno' y un `div` con clase '.dos'. Quiero igualar el ancho del `div` con el del `span`. Para leer el ancho uso  `uno.offsetWidth` y para copiarlo en el `div` uso `dos.style.width = uno.offsetWidth+'px';`, pero no consigo igualarlo.

Aquí dejo el código completo, me gustaría saber como poder hacerlo.

> Si uso `jQuery` no tengo ningún problema, sale perfecto. He observado que con el inspector del navegador las medidas son un poco diferentes ya que `offsetWidth` redondea los valores. Si uso `getBoundingClientRect.width` si me da la misma medida que en `CSS` pero al aplicar el estilo, el ancho es un poco más grande que el del primer elemento.

```js
let uno = document.querySelector('.uno');
let dos = document.querySelector('.dos');

console.log('uno offsetWidth:' + uno.offsetWidth);
console.log('uno clienttWidth:' + uno.clientWidth);
console.log('dos offsetWidth:' + dos.offsetWidth);
console.log('dos clienttWidth:' + dos.clientWidth);


dos.style.width = uno.offsetWidth + 'px';
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #DEC8C8;
}

.contenedor {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #CED9EA;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.uno {
  padding: .2rem;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dos {
  padding: .2rem;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <span class="uno">hola amigo como estas</span>
  <br>
  <div class="dos">hola</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Con `offsetWidth` recoges el ancho contando el `padding` y el borde del elemento pero al trasladarlo al `div` usas la propiedad CSS `width` que solo afecta al contenido y luego le suma el padding y el borde que has definido en los estilos, por eso no coinciden los tamaños

Comment: Es verdad no había caído en eso, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Una solución que te puede ser útil si no deseas soportar navegadores anteriores a `Internet Explorer 10` es hacer uso de [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox) y de esta manera no necesitarías hacer uso de `JavaScript`.

Si le añades la propiedad `display` con valor `inline-flex` a un contenedor que agrupe a los dos elementos y la propiedad `flex-direction` con valor `column` puedes lograr lo que deseas:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Aquí te dejo un snippet:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #DEC8C8;
}

.contenedor {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #CED9EA;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.uno {
  padding: .2rem;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dos {
  padding: .2rem;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="uno">hola amigo como estas</span>
    <div class="dos">hola</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edición:**

De todas maneras te puedo explicar lo que te sucede con `JavaScript`. Al usar [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth), los valores se redondean. Como dice la cita en el anterior enlace:

> Esta propiedad redondeará el valor a un entero. Si necesitas un valor fraccional usa: [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Pero de todas maneras este no es el problema porque la diferencia entre un valor y otro será menor a un pixel. Usando `getBoundingClientRect` estás obteniendo el valor exacto sin redondear y así todo sigue sin funcionar, por lo que te debe indicar que el problema está en otro sitio.

El problema real es que al tener los elementos, `padding` y `border`, estos valores no se tienen en cuenta cuando le apliques un ancho al elemento, y esto es debido a que el [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) por defecto es `content-box` (estarás aplicando ese tamaño al área del contenido sin contar `paddings` o `borders`). Puedes leer la cita en el anterior enlace:

> Por defecto en el [modelo de caja de CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model), el ancho y alto asignado a un elemento es aplicado solo al contenido de la caja del elemento. Si el elemento tiene algun borde (border) o relleno (padding), este es entonces añadido al ancho y alto a alcanzar el tamaño de la caja que es desplegada en pantalla. Esto significa que cuando se definen el ancho y alto, se tiene que ajustar el valor definido para permitir cualquier borde o relleno que se pueda añadir.

Una solución, es que le apliques la propiedad `box-sizing` en `border-box` a tus elementos, así las dimensiones que les asignes tendrán en cuenta el `padding` y el `border`. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo aplicando estas propiedades a todos los elementos:

```js
const uno = document.querySelector('.uno');
const dos = document.querySelector('.dos');
const { width } = uno.getBoundingClientRect();
dos.style.width = `${width}px`;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #DEC8C8;
}

.contenedor {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #CED9EA;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.uno {
  padding: .2rem;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dos {
  padding: .2rem;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">  
  <span class="uno">hola amigo como estas</span>
  <br>
  <div class="dos">hola</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué no conseguirlo por medio de **CSS**? Podemos envolver el `<span>` y el `<div>` con otro contenedor y a ese darle la propiedad `display: table`. También habría que aplicar la propiedad `display: table-row` a los elementos `.uno` y `.dos` para que se comporten como la fila de una tabla y pasen a medir lo mismo.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #DEC8C8;
}

.contenedor {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #CED9EA;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.contenedor-chat {
  display: table;
}

.uno {
    padding: .2rem;
    background-color: green;
    display: table-row;
    color: #fff;
}

.dos {
    padding: .2rem;
    background: blue;
    display: table-row;
    color: #fff;
}

.celda {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="contenedor-chat">
        <span class="uno"><p class="celda">Hola, ¿cómo estás?</p></span>
        <br>
        <div class="dos"><p class="celda">Hola.</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```